# Image representation for bpm to be compared to a spectrogram

Tags: audio, conv-neural-network, signal-processing

Disclaimer: Complete beginner with neural networks & audio representation. Please bear with me.

I have this idea for my bachelor's thesis (MIR) that involves applying a beat-like time-based pattern to constrain where a CNN-based acoustic model finds onsets/offsets. The problem is that I'm having a hard time figuring out how to implement this concept.

The initial plan was to just insert both the spectrogram and the pattern into the CNN and hope it processes it, but I don't know what format the pattern should be in. I know CNNs are best at processing images but the initial format of said pattern is "time-based" (beats per minute/second). Can this number be represented as an image to be compared to the spectrogram? If so, in what format? Or should I handle this problem in a different way? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is the BPM input a single number, either for an entire audio clip, or for longish durations of time (say 10 seconds)? How large is the time-window that your CNN looks at?

Comment: It's a single number for an entire audio clip, but the audio would be split every 20 seconds